# What is the closest thing to Pex for Visual C++?

Tags: c++, pex

Pex automagically generates unit tests for C# code.

Is there anything similar (free or commercial) for C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2005 or newer, you can use Team Test. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625%28VS.80%29.aspx) is a guide on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the mocking functionalty check out the Detours framework:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/